# Sign own certificate with ca and subjectAltNames

Tags: ssl

I found a easy tutorial which explains a few steps to create a own self signed ca.crt which can be used to sign keys for a mqtt broker:
http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-tls/

That is a great tutorial but some librarys need to have a set subjectAltName in the .crt.
So i followed: http://wiki.cacert.org/FAQ/subjectAltName and created a server.csr with the

```sh
     Requested Extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage:
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:127.0.0.1, DNS:localhost
```

Now I have problems with the last step. How can I use the ca.crt and ca.key to generate a server.crt from the server.csr (with the extensions) ?

Hope for your help ;)

T

Comment: (1) this is not a programming question/problem (2) if using OpenSSL, as your link implies, use `openssl ca` configured with `copy_extensions` and other things as needed; see similar https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371997/creating-a-local-ssl-certificate (where it is ontopic) and the man page on your system or [on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ca.html)